# Empty-ing innerHTML increases number of DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, html, memory-management, memory-leaks

I created a very simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id='div'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I opened it in Chrome, run Timeline and I saw **Number of nodes: 9**.
Then I executed `document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = ''` and noticed that **Number of nodes: 10**.

Note 1: Number of nodes became 9 again after restarting Timeline

Note 2: If execute `document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = ''` several times Number of nodes jumps from 9 to 10 and back to 9:

[image: 10 nodes at the timeline]

Can someone explain why `document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = ''` causes a creation of a new node? Why it's collected not always by GC? What is the other(better) way to clean the node content?

Comment: I guess the initial parsing doesn't create a text node as it's not really useful.

Comment: Is this actually a memory leak? If so, how do you know? Maybe it's just some bug in the dev tools.

Comment: ...and we seem to be missing code. Why haven't you posted a full example of what you're doing? Or is this executed in the console?

Comment: @cookiemonster, yes, it was executed in the console. And I'm not sure if it's a leak. I just want to know why it's so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was asked to guys from [igalia](http://www.igalia.com/) and the answer in short is "It is created because in the following part of the JavaScript, it might be referenced".
So JavaScript might refer to the DOM node to fill it with a calculated value. Hence why it is hard to optimize this out. It could only be optimized if all JavaScript code has been read and executed. Hence why it is easier to start with an empty DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in chrome 33. Effectively, there are 9 initial nodes:

```
#document
    doctype
    html
        head
        #text
        body
            #text
            div
            #text
```

If I execute

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.innerHTML = '';
```

Nothing especial happens.

```
div.childNodes;
```

returns an empty NodeList. But if I write

```
div.innerHTML = ' '; //<- with space
```

Then a new node is created.

If I do that operation multiple times, the node count grows and then suddenly diminishes. The reason? Garbage collection doest not occur every time a node is removed (it would be hightly inefficient). Chrome's V8 has a reserved heap for young-generation objects. Only when this space is full does garbage collection occur, deleting unused objects and promoting other objects to the old-generation heap.

Comment: Looks reasonable but I didn't insert space, there was an empty string.

Comment: Are you using Chrome 33?

Comment: Yes, Version 33.0.1750.154